# I am getting an error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' " while running my flutter program at line no 57

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and getting error -> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List'. Following is the code.
It is giving error while running the code at " List snap = snapshot.data;"

```
    class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
    getMethod() async {
      String theUrl = 'http://ananyananu.000webhostapp.com/getData.php';
      var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(theUrl), headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
      var responsBody = json.decode(res.body);
      print ('I reached here');
      print('responsBody');
      return responsBody;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Connect to Local Host') ,
         centerTitle: true,
         backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
       ),
       body: FutureBuilder(
       future: getMethod(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
       List snap = snapshot.data;
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
           }
       if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Center(
               child: Text('Error Fetching Data'),);
           }

           return ListView.builder(
             itemCount: snap.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return ListTile(
                 title: Text("head: ${snap[index]['heading']}"),
                 subtitle: Text("body ${snap[index] ['body']}"),
                 );
             },
```

Comment: Which is the line where your error happened?

Comment: move the `List snap = snapshot.data` to right above this line:  `return ListView.builder(
` If you still get an error, please post the `getMethod()` code

Comment: Dear Mr Lajos : Thanks for suggession. As suggested I moved the List snap = snapshot.data to right above this line: return ListView.builder. Now it is giving error "  type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' ". getMethod() code is at line no 2 to 9 in my post.